# How to insert a new same-level headline after current one?

Tags: org-mode, insert

Suppose I have an `org-mode` buffer that contains the outline shown below, and that point is at the position indicated by the ▮ character.

```
* foo
** bar
*** baz
    - eenie
      - yabba
      - dabba▮
      - doo
    - meenie
    - minie
* frobozz
** quux
```

Call this particular configuration (buffer content + point position) the *initial state*.

If I now run `org-insert-heading` (IOW, I type `M-<RET>`), I get a new list item:

```
* foo
** bar
*** baz
    - eenie
      - yabba
      - dabba
      - ▮
      - doo
    - meenie
    - minie
* frobozz
** quux
```

Now, I think of a "heading" in an `org-mode` outline as a line beginning with `*`'s.  Therefore, if I interpret the name of the command `org-insert-heading` *literally*, I would have expected that running `org-insert-heading` from the *initial state* would have produced the following, which I'll refer to as the *desired state*:

```
* foo
** bar
*** baz
    - eenie
      - yabba
      - dabba
      - doo
    - meenie
    - minie
*** ▮
* frobozz
** quux
```

My question is:

> does the `org-mode` interface already provides a more direct way<sup>1</sup> to achieve the *desired state* starting from the *initial state*?

---

(In case that the answer to this question is "no", then a distant second-best would be a way to override `org-insert-heading` so that it behaves the way I think it should (i.e. always inserting a **heading**, namely a line starting with `*`s, and thus producing the *desired state* from the *initial state*), together with a new custom command that preserves the default behavior of `org-insert-heading` in the *initial state*.  I'd appreciate any help I can get with this too.)

---

<sup>1</sup> I stress that my question does not ask for *any* way, by hook or crook, to get to the *desired state* from the *initial state*.  I realize that, if nothing else, I can always "revert to plain Emacs", so to speak: for example, I can move point as shown below

```
* foo
** bar
*** baz
    - eenie
      - yabba
      - dabba
      - doo
    - meenie
    - minie▮
* frobozz
** quux
```

...and then type the sequence <kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd>, to arrive at the *desired state*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`C-<RET>`, `org-insert-heading-respect-content`

Other options are listed in the [manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-Editing.html)